# integration by parts? 2 variables Expected value.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, expected-value

Can someone please give some detail on the blue square steps? Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: That should be integrated with respect to $y$.

Comment: Integration by parts is not needed, just expand the brackets and integrate each term separately.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^{d} \dfrac{2y(d-y)}{d^2} dy = \dfrac{1}{d^2} \int_0^{d} \left(2dy-2y^2\right) dy = \dfrac{1}{d^2} [dy^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3]_0^d = \dfrac{d}{3}.
$$

Comment: John Doe, Should it be dx instead dy  or it was a typo from the original solution.?

Comment: @user95432 The original solution you posted had a typo where they wrote $$E[Y] = \int_0^d yf(y)\,dx$$ It should be $$E[Y] = \int_0^d yf(y)\,dy$$ This solution posted by ericc shows how to compute that integral.